# Matplotlib: how to edit a figure that has been closed

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
a.show()
```

after closing the canvas I can show the figure stored in variable a at any time using a.show(), but how can I edit this figure?

Comment: What do you mean by edit the figure? [pyplot](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html)

Comment: @AlyAbdelaziz any kind of change to the figure `a` for example `plt.xlabel('anything')`

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: "anything" can be "everything". Check the pyplot documentation in the link above for all the available things you can do.

Answer (score 1):

As with most things matplotlib, you should keep track of your Figure and Axes objects directly. The you can do "anything"

So your example becomes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2,3,4])
fig.show()

# <close the figure>
ax.set_xlabel('Post-mortem')
```

Comment: The OP question is too broad and generic. In this case you can do anything to the fig(ax) or (a) in his case after `show`

Comment: using `fig.show()` after the end of your code shows the figure without the changes done after closing it `ax.set_xlabel('Post-mortem')`.

Comment: @OmarOrabi i'll ask again, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am taking MITx: 6.00.1x on edx.org, and in plotting lecture he shows how to make several figures and edit them but he is doing it by changing the current figure accessed and doing the desired changes, the problem is that he can view the figure without calling show() method since he is using ipython in spyder on the other hand I am using terminal and need to use show() method to view the figure then I close it and proceed to edit these figures, If I switch between figures without show() and exiting the figure I can do the changes I want. :)

Comment: so you specifically *don't* want to close the figure. you want to turn interactive mode on. `plt.ion()`.

Comment: this could work but I think it is more clean to be able to close the figure then reopen it when needed. I think if there is no solution I can edit the code from the beginning and  make it a function to call it when needed, thanks

Comment: in what way is that "clean"? regardless, that's not how matplotlib works. you close a figure, its gone.